# How to use wifi_station_connection_get_bssid()?

Tags: c++, native, blackberry-10

From the documentation -> https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/core/com.qnx.doc.wifi_service.lib_ref/topic/wifi_station_connection_get_bssid.html

Does anyone know how to use this function call? Tried this with no success, only get an integer stored in my variable.

```
uint8_t *target = new uint8_t[WIFI_BSSID_ADDR_LEN];
qDebug() << "Error: " + QString::number(wifi_station_connection_get_bssid(target));
qDebug() << *target;
```

Printout is

```
NavigationPane: NavigationPaneOnFwdTransitionDone: emitting push transition ended for page: 12 client top: 12 
"Error: 0" 
32
```

The error code is a "success" yet I don't get the BSSID out of it.

Comment: Check the [return code](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/core/com.qnx.doc.wifi_service.lib_ref/topic/wifi_result_t.html), that might tell you why the result isn't what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're specifying `*target` when you create your `QString`. That's telling the compiler "Make a QString from the first `char` in `target`". That's exactly what it's doing.

Assuming this returns the BSSID as a NUL-terminated string, you probably want to change it to:

```
qDebug << QString(target);
```

The documentation doesn't really say, but based on using `uint8_t` instead of `char` this may well be delivering the BSSID as a numeric IP address instead of a string. If so, you'll need to step through the bytes of the address and convert each to a readable form before displaying them. For a (poor) example, something on this general order:

```
char buffer[16];
sprintf(buffer, "%x.%x.%x.%x", target[0], target[1], target[2], target[3]);
```

Right now, this is hard-coded to convert four bytes (fine for IPv4, insufficient for IPv6), to hexadecimal. Proper support for IPv4 and v6, nationalize display, etc., becomes rather more elaborate, but I think this should be enough to at least get you started in the right general direction.